# Why is my function call no longer working?

Tags: android, eclipse, email

I had a mail function in my application that was working fine until today, and I have not touched in about a month.

Here is a link to the mail program I put in my app: http://www.jondev.net/articles/Sending_Emails_without_User_Intervention_%28no_Intents%29_in_Android

My problem is in the conditional, m.send() is not being called for some reason, but the else statement is working fine. I am getting no errors at all and the catch is not catching anything. Can someone please tell me what happened to my program?

```
public void Mailing(String inputName, String inputPassword)
{
    Mail m = new Mail(inputName, inputPassword); 

    String[] toArr = {"fake@gmail.com"}; 
    m.setTo(toArr); 
    m.setFrom(inputName); 
    m.setSubject("Daily Time Card"); 
    m.setBody(""); 

    try 
    { 
      m.addAttachment(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() + "/test"); 

      if(m.send()) 
      { 
        Toast.makeText(TaskReminderActivity.this, "Email was sent successfully.",  Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); 
      }
      else
      {
        Toast.makeText(TaskReminderActivity.this, "Email was not sent successfully.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); 
      }

    } catch(Exception e) { 
      Toast.makeText(TaskReminderActivity.this, "There was a problem sending the  email.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
      Toast.makeText(TaskReminderActivity.this, "Value of User Name is " + inputName, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
      Toast.makeText(TaskReminderActivity.this, "Value of Password is " + inputPassword, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
      Toast.makeText(TaskReminderActivity.this, "Value of Attachment is " + Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() + "/test.txt", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
      Log.e("MailApp", "Could not send email", e); 
    } 
}
```

Comment: See if the mail provider has changed its settings..

Comment: I know it is a vague question, but I was hoping someone with a similar experience might have an answer, I can not see any reason why it should not be working.

Comment: @Anonymous That does not seem to be the case, gmail's SMTP still seems to be the same.